# Yum is stuck at 0 bites

Tags: linux, command-line

[image]

I cant seem to do any yum commands. They never end

Comment: `yum clean all` ran and ended .... btw, the term is `bytes`

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! Please, [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you either cannot access the AlmaLinux repository server, or your system has an incorrect repository configuration for `yum`. Check the `/etc/yum.repos.d/*.repo` files: what is the value of the `baseurl` parameter in them?

If that seems correct, it's time to do some real network troubleshooting.

`ping 8.8.8.8` only proves that ICMP packets can go both ways between your system and Google's public DNS server. Modern firewalls can easily allow ICMP while blocking TCP and UDP, or vice versa. So pinging a DNS server only proves that very basic IP and ICMP connectivity exists, but it does **not** prove that you can actually get your DNS queries answered by the server.

So you should test *the exact things* you'll need to have working
For example, if you want to use 8.8.8.8 as your DNS server, test it with e.g. `dig google.com @8.8.8.8`. If it says `;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached`, that's bad.

Next step: can a normal (non-diagnostic) program resolve the hostname you actually need? You seem to be trying to reach AlmaLinux repositories, so try `getent hosts repo.almalinux.org`. The response should show repo.almalinux.org's IP address. If there is no response (just a new command prompt), your system failed to resolve that name. Run `resolvectl status` if it exists; if not, look at `/etc/resolv.conf`. Also run `grep ^hosts /etc/nsswitch.conf` and verify that the answer includes at least one of the keywords `dns` or `resolve`.

If that also works, try `curl -I https://repo.almalinux.org`. If the response starts with something like `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`, your system will be able to contact the repository server.

If you can resolve the hostname, but `curl` fails, you might try a `traceroute` **using the TCP protocol and the port you actually need**, and see how far you can get. Such a trace usually requires root privileges. HTTPS is port 443, so the command would be:

```
sudo traceroute -T -p 443 repo.almalinux.org
```

Or if you had a problem with DNS access to 8.8.8.8, you could test with:

```
sudo traceroute -T -p 53 8.8.8.8
```

DNS uses port 53 with both UDP and TCP: UDP for quick simple queries, but if there is more data in response than can fit in a single UDP packet (which gets more common with geographically distributed services and DNSSEC) and the client needs all the data, TCP is used.

With all this information, you will be able to give a problem report with much more useful facts.